# My web app is duplicating user input for post, not showing user deleted unless page refresh for delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, ejs

I have a small app that's written in Javascript that's a to-do list. The frontend is simple Javascript that takes data from an array, then allows the user to add items to the array (post data). When they click on an item, it should be deleted it

Now, it *sort of* works. So when the user enters a item and press enter or clicks submit, it lists the item twice?!

When the user clicks an item to remove it, it only removes when the page is refreshed (F5). The location.reload() method doesn't appear to fire, or the success isn't registering

Here is the front end, showing the duplication:

[image]

Here is the js that controls the post and deletes (todo_list.js):

```
//These are ajax requests
//in the controller post method we will be using this code
$(document).ready(function(){
//when click submit
  $('form').on('submit', function(){
//create item
      let item = $('form input');
      //create todo with value from item above
      //add to data array in the controller
      let todo = {item: item.val()};
//send post request to post in controller
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/todo',
        //pass todo as data
        data: todo,
        success: function(data){
          //do something with the data via front-end framework
//reload page when new item is added
          location.reload();
        }
      });

      return false;

  });

  $('li').on('click', function(){
    //replace spaces with hyphens
      var item = $(this).text().replace(/ /g, '-');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/todo/' + item,
        success: function(data){
          location.reload();
        }
      });
  });    
});
```

Here's the ejs file for the webpage (todo.ejs):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>To-do list</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- below works because of the middleware setting for static files -->
  <script src="/assets/todo_list.js"></script>
  <link href="/assets/styles_example_app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My todo list</h1>
  <div id="todo-table">
    <form method="POST">
      <input type = "text" name="item" placeholder="Add new item..." required />
      <button type = "submit">Add items</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
        <% for(let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++){ %>
          <li><%= todos[i].item %></li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="/assets/todo_list.js"></script>
</html>
```

In the above, the for loop is needed to show the existing items in the array (data), here is the controller:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//storing some data to display on the webpage. This is the array we're working with

let data = [{item: 'get milk'}, {item: 'walk dog'}, {item: 'kick Joey'}];

let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});


module.exports = function(app){
  //now we're exporting and calling in app.js, we can make the routes
  app.get('/todo', function(req, res){
    //render a get request when user visit /todo in browser
    //pass the data from the above data object onto the page
    res.render('todo', {todos: data});
  });

  //handler for post request for when user enters to do list item todo_list.js
  app.post('/todo', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
      //grab data from array and push user input data to array
      //added new item to data array
      data.push(req.body);
      //once added, render page
      res.redirect('/todo');
  });
  //handler for deleting the files
  app.delete('/todo/:item', function(req,res){
    //filter out item that we're trying to delete
    data = data.filter(function(todo){
      // bottom is returning true or false
      // if false, remove from array
      return todo.item.replace(/ /g, '-') !== req.params.item;
      res.redirect('/todo');
    })
  });
}
```

What i'm confused about is how the input post data can be duplicated, and why the deleted items, when clicked, don't reload the page. If I manually reload, they're deleted. I feel like i'm missing something small since it all sort of works, albeit badly

Does anyone have any suggestions?

So far i've tried changing the jquery call to google (one suggestion I found here), also in the EJS file specifying post in the form tag as the method

Thanks

Comment: Sorry if this appears a bit amateur, it's my first project and so the comments are to jog my memory as to what it's doing and how it links together

Comment: are you sure the "DELETE" success callback is called? Did you try to place a breakpoint there, or at least a console log?

Comment: I just tried adding a console.log -> "success: function(data){
          location.reload();
          console.log('it deleted');" and it doesn't log to the console, but when I reload my page, the clicked on item in the webpage disappears

Comment: Try adding an error callback to the DELETE, and do console.log(arguments) in it, so we could see if it fails and why. Also, the network tab, check 'preserve logs' and see if the 'DELETE' api has 200 returned, I doubt that. And I think that's the reason.

Comment: `location.reload();` is going to refresh the page, so anything you add after that isn't going to be relevant (you _might_ see the console log briefly, but doubtful).

Comment: @Lukasz The delete API did not have 200 returned. todo_list.js has 304 status returned when adding new items. Nothing logged when clicking list items to delete, but they're removed on refresh. I'm sorry I haven't gotten to callbacks and error handling in my tutorial yet, but thanks for your patience

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution (a hack not a real solution):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/todo/' + item,
    always: function(data){
      location.reload();
    }
  });
```

Above could work because it will call the callback whatever the response is, but is is not a proper solution, the proper solution would be to make sure you have a proper response code returned according to the HTTP STATUS CODES: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes and it is properly handled via success/error callbacks.

Third, you are using ajax to avoid reloads, example: you could return the up-to-date list of items on every api call and re-render the component after every api call, not reload.

Comment: Strangely enough, that didn't reload the li items. I tried changing the controller to render the page for both the post and delete as a test, but it won't autorefresh the list if you use res.render(). Using res.redirect works for POST but not delete. This is very confusing

Comment: On your server, instead of res.redirect('/todo'); do res.send("OK"), this should return 200 and call the success callback, is it doing this?

Comment: No weirdly, in network, when clicking an item the status is '(pending)'. It makes sense to me what you're saying about capturing the response. Could it be that the initiator is jquery.min.js:4, but in my ejs file i'm using version 1.12.1? Scrap that, i've tried updating the hotlink, no luck

Comment: I doubt the initiator has anything to do with it. I am sorry, I run out of ideas. I think you have to focus first on returning the right status code from your server (this can help: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.delete.method), after that, all the callbacks will work fine. Let us know once you find the solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and for your time, I appreciate it